# Is there a website where i can just sell drawings?

Tags: business, games

I am 17 years old and wanted to find a way to make money from my anime/realism drawings. I'm kinda looking more for a website torward startup game designers who just need a drawing done and are willing to pay. Is there a website like that?

Ive went to "outsource.com" but i've seen a lot of reveiws saying that its a scam and i feel like its almost impossible to get a sale on websites like "fineartamerica.com"

Answer (score 1):

Besides DeviantArt, as mentioned by @Roozbeh, there are two more that I have personally used before and therefore recommend -

[Artsy](https://www.artsy.net) - A massive, venture-funded online gallery that sells art from thousands of artists from all over the world.

[Artpal](http://www.artpal.com) - Fast-growing (and free) gallery to sell art and buy art. No membership fees. ArtPal is completely free. You receive between 95-percent and 100-percent of the sale price when they sell your art.

Answer (score 0):

[DeviantArt.com](http://www.deviantart.com/) and artists groups in [Facebook.com](http://facebook.com)

I haven't tried selling my art in these, but I have done some collaborations.

- In DeviantArt you can have your own private webpage with your own touches, contributing prints and selling copies and files are a good way to make money. Also, collaborating with groups and the community may help your profit grow. Signing up is free and you can get core-member status if you found it suits your needs. I suggest you give it shot!
- On Facebook you can join groups to introduce yourself. gather and notify people about your social events, like galleries, sells, new works, new skills and a lot more.